# I want to convert csv file to xml

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to convert csv file to xml and i want to send the converted xml file to a queue in activemq..Is there any sample code or any reference websites or blogs please help to find sample code for this program..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Bindy](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html) and [Xstream](http://camel.apache.org/xstream.html) components. From http://workingwithqueues.blogspot.ch/2012/07/converting-csv-to-xml-with-camel-bindy.html (with a JMS endpoint instead of a file endpoint):

```
DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.package.dto");
from("file://TEST?fileName=Employee.csv")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .marshal()
    .xstream()
    .to("jms:queue:FOO.BAR");
```

For connecting to JMS have a look at the [JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) and [ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter...I have this example before its converting file from csv to xml and it can't able to connect with activemq..

Comment: @Rahulbujji For connecting to ActiveMQ have a look at http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Comment: @Rahulbujji If the answer helped you, you may mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.mycompany.conversion;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Greeting {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Person")
    @XmlElement(name = "persons")
    private List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPerson(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

}

========================================================================================
package org.mycompany.conversion;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.CsvRecord;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.DataField;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Person {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    @XmlElement
    private int id;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @DataField(pos = 3)
    @XmlElement
    private int age;



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
======================================================================================
package org.mycompany.conversion;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;

public class CsvConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
        JAXBContext con = JAXBContext.newInstance(Greeting.class);
        xmlDataFormat.setContext(con);
        DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Person.class);
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("file:src/main/data/in/csv?noop=true").split().tokenize("\n").unmarshal(bindy)
                        // constanr(true):-aggregate all using same expression
                        .aggregate(constant(true), new AttachAggregation())
                        //mandatory after aggregate
                        .completionTimeout(100)//end after this gives problem
                        .marshal(xmlDataFormat).log("xml body is ${body}")
                        .to("file:src/main/data/in/xml?fileName=convertedXml.xml");// .aggregate(new
                                                                                    // AttachAggreagation());
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
=========================================================================================

package org.mycompany.conversion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class AttachAggregation implements AggregationStrategy {

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList();
    Greeting gre = new Greeting();

    @Override
//person-address
    // greeting-user
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

        if (oldExchange == null) {
            Person newBody1 = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Person.class);
            list.add(newBody1);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            Person newBody2 = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Person.class);
            list.add(newBody2);

            gre.setPerson(list);
            oldExchange.getIn().setBody(gre);
            return oldExchange;
        }

    }

}
```